# Rollup js: how to make a closure like d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, rollupjs

Most of what I use javascript for is d3 and the rest of my javascript knowledge was self learned by looking at examples, reading docs, etc. The point is my "in-depth" knowledge of javascript is not so deep...

Since I mostly work with d3 I have written a lot of my own functions and closures (as suggested by Bostock in [Towards Reusable Charts](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/)) which build on top of d3.

To keep track of all the code I have written them in separate files and to use my collection I have tried a few ways such as dynamically appending script tags to the head of the document, concatenating files, etc

Ideally, I should make proper module of my code and bundle it together.

So I have set off on that path and stumbled across rollup and this [tutorial](https://code.lengstorf.com/learn-rollup-js/) by Lengstrof.

I tried following it and got it to work with some minor changes (e.g. it assumes `babel-core` is already installed and currently there is an issue with `postcss`.

Anyway, I made a small repo to demonstrate my use case ([project repo](https://gitlab.com/SumNeuron/rollup-closure-test)). It has some modules which includes helper functions, some prototypes, and some closures.

Ideally, these would all be exported into a closure / object just like `d3` (e.g. `myClos`) where I could then call any of the functions I have written.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to do this and did not find relevant examples / tutorials on how to do this. Also, in doing this, would I have to then call my helper functions like `myClos.helper1()`.

Anyway, I would greatly appreciate your help. The ideal end would be to have the rolled-up file `myclos.min.js` work like `d3` where I include the script tag and then `myclos` is in the `global-namespace`.

Many thanks in advance for you assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're following the appropriate format for importing/referencing your external helpers/modules (e.g., from your `main` file: (esmodules) `import foo from './helper1'; console.log(foo.helper1())` or (commonjs) `const foo = require('./helper1'); console.log(foo.helper1())`.) In the module you're trying to export from (`helper1`): (esm) `export default helper1`, (cjs) `module.exports = helper1`. [The Rollup docs](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en#creating-your-first-bundle) have good examples of this.